# Disable hiding of address bar on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I'm working on a mobile website which has "pages" that have div's which take up the screens full size and you can scroll between each one. The problem is, the window resizes whenever a user scrolls downward because the address bar hides. This causes problems when you scroll to the complete bottom and the address bar then hides.

Is it possible to have the address bar always show on mobile devices?

Comment: I believe you can make the height of `<body>` the same as the viewport and add a scrollbar to `<body>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can wrap your HTML with `div` and do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Fhe2x/show

```
$("html, body, #wrapper").css({
    height: $(window).height()
});
```

It works on Android and iOS.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the div is the same size as the body but is scrollable. This might work, I'll give it a try soon. Thanks!

Comment: This is excellent. Also, if you need to keep multiple divs (maybe because you have anchors or fixed-scrolling javascript functions), you can apply Derek's example to every single "fullpage-div": the address bar won't disappear when scrolling, but there won't be resizing problems. You can then keep full screen mode without scrolling "bugs"). Just tested on Android 5.0 with Chrome.

Comment: THANK YOU! Works like a charm. I cannot express my gratitude enough as I've spent 5 hours trying to solve this. I'm not even bothered by seeing jQuery in a vanilla question.

Comment: Fun fact - it actually doesn't prevent the address bar from hiding, but does prevent layout shift caused by the window changing height.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve this is to scroll in a container, rather than scrolling the document.

E.g.:

```
<html><body>
  <div id="scrollable-content"> ... all your content here ... </div>
</body></html>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#scrollable-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at iPhone? I don't know about Android, but on iOS 7 for iPhone it's not possible. One thing you could do is use `minimal-ui` to have an always-minimized navigation bar, keeping a consistent size for the window:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">`

http://visuellegedanken.de/2014-03-13/viewport-meta-tag-minimal-ui/

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I want the complete opposite. I'm currently looking at Android but I will be looking at an iOS browser at some point.

Comment: Update: `minimal-ui` is gone from iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Since this problem arises on mobile so use media query and put the position of your body and html as "fixed", Now, you will be see that the search bar does not hide. But for pages which have to be scrolled it will not scroll.
To solve that, use overflow-y: scroll;

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    /* to prevent auto hiding of the search bar */
    body, html{
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
}
```