# How to always display ios bottom browser bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, scrolltop

I have a mobile website with a button in the footer fixed on the bottom. When you click on the bottom, the browser bar in the bottom comes up. See image:
[image]

My solution to this is to always display the bottom browser bar with:

```
html{
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
body{
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

But then my JQuery `scrollTop` doesn't work because of `overflow`.
Does someone know of a solution to always display the `bottom browser bar`, or how to make `scrollTop` work with `overflow`?

Comment: The bottom browser bar is the bar of the browser not the webpage right?

Comment: @WimPruiksma Exactly. I have a footer fixed on the bottom, when you click there, the ios browser bar pops up

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link. [Disable hiding of address bar on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164503/disable-hiding-of-address-bar-on-mobile)

Webbrowsers are checking your configs for screen width and height.

Add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">` into your meta data

Comment: Actually I want the ios browser bar to always show.

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work. The browser bar still disappears.

Comment: Don't know if its possible to disable a browsers function. I know its possible to make full screen but not how to disable functions like that